# Set screen blank and suspend timers on certain times on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, power-management, lock-screen

I would like to have several configurations about screen blanking and suspend times based on the time of the day and day of the week so, from 9 to 5 on weekdays, the screen stays on and the computer never suspends, but any other time the computer can turn off the screen or suspend if I'm away from the computer.

It would be neat to set up a washing machine or go do the dishes while working from home and know that I'll hear the notification if needed and it wont just go to sleep

I was thinking this could probably be done with a cron-job to do this but I can't quite figure the search term to find how to set those up through the terminal.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a tool that already does this?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with gnome desktop 42.9 on Wayland at the moment, but I'd probably be willing to switch desktop environments for this feature.